# Make button active if cache object is 5 minutes old

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I've got an ASP.Net page that displays a dashboard of data, and I want the viewer to be able to refresh the data manually.  However, I don't want them to be able to just click Refresh over and over again.  I have the data cached with a 15 minute expiration, and I want the user to be able to manually refresh if the cache is more than 5 minutes old.  What's the best way for me to accomplish this?

GetCachedData method

```
    private DashboardViewModel GetCachedData(int boardNumber)
    {
        string area = ConvertBoard(boardNumber);
        var cache = HttpContext.Cache;

        if (cache[area + "Dashboard"] == null)
        {
            cache.Add(area + "Dashboard", GetDashData(boardNumber), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }

        return (DashboardViewModel)cache[area + "Dashboard"];
    }
```

Comment: so setTimeout and enable it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...I don't want the button to be active 5 minutes after the page loads as the viewer could go to other pages that utilize the cached data, but rather 5 minutes after the cache is populated.  When the data is 5 minutes old or more, a button in the view would become active.  Am I missing what you're saying?

Comment: So you need to record a time when the query can be run again.  You store that value and put it on the page. You calculate the difference and set a timer to enable it at that time.

Comment: So I would do something like: `window.onload(function() { var btn = document.getElementById('refreshBtnId'); var secondsTillRefreshAllowed = <<how do I get info from the HttpContext cache??>>; btn.setTimeout(func1, (cacheRefreshTimer - @DateTime.Now) ); function func1 () { document.getElementById('refreshBtnId').removeAttribute('disabled');} }

That look kinda right?